# Switch Case Statement With Greater Than Operator?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, operators

The following IF statements in my code do not work. How can I add a "greater than" operator in a Switch Case format or an IF statement in this scenario? I need it to say IF Machine is 1 and numOfBends > 7 then setupMins = 60. IF Machine is 2 and numOfBends > 7 then setupMins = 60. IF Machine is 3 and numOfBends > 7 then setupMins = 60.

```
/**
 * bendingSetupHours
 * @customfunction bendingSetupHours
 * @param {number} numOfBends 
 * @param {number} bendLengthInches 
 * @returns {number} bendingSetupHours
 */
function bendingSetupHours(numOfBends, bendLengthInches) {
  var machine;
  var setupMins;
  switch(bendLengthInches) {
    case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9: case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15: case 16:
    case 17: case 18: case 19: case 20: case 21: case 22: case 23: case 24: case 25: case 26: case 27: case 27: case 29: case 30: case 31:
    case 32: case 33: case 34: case 45: case 36:
      machine = 1;
      break;
    case 37: case 38: case 39: case 40: case 41: case 42: case 43: case 44: case 45: case 46: case 47: case 48: case 49: case 50: case 51:
    case 52: case 53: case 54: case 55: case 56: case 57: case 58: case 59: case 60: case 61: case 62: case 63: case 64: case 65: case 66:
    case 67: case 68: case 69: case 70: case 71:
      machine = 2;
      break;
    case "":
      machine = 0;
      break;
  default:
      machine = 3;
  } 
  switch("" + machine + numOfBends) {
      case "" + 1 + 0: case "" + 1 + 1: case "" + 1 + 2: case "" + 1 + 3: case "" + 2 + 0: case "" + 2 + 1: case "" + 2 + 2: case "" + 2 + 3:
        setupMins = 15;
        break;
      case "" + 1 + 5: case "" + 1 + 6: case "" + 1 + 7: case "" + 3 + 0: case "" + 3 + 1: case "" + 3 + 2: case "" + 3 + 3:
        setupMins = 30;
        break;
      if (numOfBends >7 && machine ==1) {
        setupMins = 60;
        break;
      }
      case "" + 2 + 5: case "" + 2 + 6: case "" + 2 + 7:
        setupMins = 45;
        break;
      if (numOfBends >7 && machine ==2) {
        setupMins = 90;
        break;
      }
      case "" + 3 + 4: case "" + 3 + 5: case "" + 3 + 6: case "" + 3 + 7:
        setupMins = 60;
        break;
        if (numOfBends >7 && machine ==3) {
          setupMins = 120;
          break;
        }
    default:
      setupMins = 0;
  }
     return (setupMins / 60); 
}
```

Comment: You `break` it before the `if` statement can run

Comment: And yes, you definitely should not use a `switch` statement here.

Comment: You cannot put conditions in `switch case` statements. Youd be much better off using an IF ELSE chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 /**
   * bendingSetupHours
   * @customfunction bendingSetupHours
   * @param {number} numOfBends 
   * @param {number} bendLengthInches 
   * @returns {number} bendingSetupHours
   */
  function bendingSetupHours(numOfBends, bendLengthInches) {
    var machine;
    var setupMins;
    switch(bendLengthInches) {
      case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9: case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15: case 16:
      case 17: case 18: case 19: case 20: case 21: case 22: case 23: case 24: case 25: case 26: case 27: case 27: case 29: case 30: case 31:
      case 32: case 33: case 34: case 45: case 36:
        machine = 1;
        break;
      case 37: case 38: case 39: case 40: case 41: case 42: case 43: case 44: case 45: case 46: case 47: case 48: case 49: case 50: case 51:
      case 52: case 53: case 54: case 55: case 56: case 57: case 58: case 59: case 60: case 61: case 62: case 63: case 64: case 65: case 66:
      case 67: case 68: case 69: case 70: case 71:
        machine = 2;
        break;
      case "":
        machine = 0;
        break;
    default:
        machine = 3;
    } 
    if (machine == 1 && numOfBends == 0 || numOfBends == 1 || numOfBends == 2 || numOfBends == 3) {
        setupMins = 15;
    } else if (machine == 1 && numOfBends == 5 || numOfBends == 6 || numOfBends == 7) {
        setupMins = 30;
    } else if (machine == 1 && numOfBends > 7) {
        setupMins = 60;
    } else if (machine == 2 && numOfBends == 0 || numOfBends == 1 || numOfBends == 2 || numOfBends == 3) {
        setupMins = 15;
    } else if (machine == 2 && numOfBends == 4 || numOfBends == 5 || numOfBends == 6 || numOfBends == 7) {
        setupMins = 45;
    } else if (machine == 2 && numOfBends > 7) {
        setupMins = 90;
    } else if (machine == 3 && numOfBends == 0 || numOfBends == 1 || numOfBends == 2 || numOfBends == 3) {
        setupMins = 30;
    } else if (machine == 3 && numOfBends == 4 || numOfBends == 5 || numOfBends == 6 || numOfBends == 7) {
        setupMins = 60;
    } else if (machine == 3 && numOfBends > 7) {
        setupMins = 120;
    } else {
        setupMins = 0;
    }
        return (setupMins / 60);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp more than a correction.